# Unable to connect to MySQL database using xampp and pdo

Tags: php

I can't connect to database. I am using xampp, it shows a blank page.

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host = 127.0.0.1; dbname:test', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('ne moze');
}
```

Comment: According to the code you have posted, you have only set up your PDO, you haven't actually tried to do anything with the DB. There must be some more code here.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: What are your expectations? Should you not get a blank page? If so why?

Answer (score 0):

first.. activate the error output..

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

try{ $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host = 127.0.0.1; dbname:test', 'root', '');
...
```